# Why is there 1s sleep after each waypoint upload?

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

I'm working with DJI Onboard-SDK-ROS and DJI matrice M600. When I upload waypoint mission I have to wait long time for upload to be completed (1s for every waypoint precisely). The problem is in `dji_sdk_node_mission_services.cpp` in method `missionWpUploadCallback`.

Here:

```
for (auto waypoint : request.waypoint_task.mission_waypoint) {
        wpData.latitude = waypoint.latitude * C_PI / 180;
        wpData.longitude = waypoint.longitude * C_PI / 180;
        wpData.altitude = waypoint.altitude;
        wpData.damping = waypoint.damping_distance;
        wpData.yaw = waypoint.target_yaw;
        wpData.gimbalPitch = waypoint.target_gimbal_pitch;
        wpData.turnMode = waypoint.turn_mode;
        wpData.hasAction = waypoint.has_action;
        wpData.actionTimeLimit = waypoint.action_time_limit;
        wpData.actionNumber = 15;
        wpData.actionRepeat = waypoint.waypoint_action.action_repeat;
        wpData.index = i;
        std::copy(waypoint.waypoint_action.command_list.begin(),
                  waypoint.waypoint_action.command_list.end(), wpData.commandList);
        std::copy(waypoint.waypoint_action.command_parameter.begin(),
                  waypoint.waypoint_action.command_parameter.end(),
                  wpData.commandParameter);

        uploadAck = vehicle->missionManager->wpMission->uploadIndexData(
                &wpData, WAIT_TIMEOUT);

        ROS_DEBUG("uploaded waypoint lat: %f lon: %f alt: %f", waypoint.latitude,
                  waypoint.longitude, waypoint.altitude);

        response.cmd_set = (int) uploadAck.ack.info.cmd_set;
        response.cmd_id = (int) uploadAck.ack.info.cmd_id;
        response.ack_data = (unsigned int) uploadAck.ack.data;

        if (ACK::getError(uploadAck.ack)) {
            ACK::getErrorCodeMessage(uploadAck.ack, __func__);
            response.result = false;
        } else {
            response.result = true;
        }

        ROS_INFO("uploaded the %dth waypoint\n", (wpData.index + 1));
        i += 1;
        sleep(1);
    }
```

When I commented the `sleep(1)` command in the end of the cycle the mission still got uploaded and executed (at least in simulation).

So my question is what's the reason behind the `sleep(1)` command and is it necessary?

I have seen question about the same thing [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/issues/88) but as I said above, the mission is uploaded without problem even without the sleep.